# Apple Captive Portal displaying "Success" instead of closing

Tags: javascript, iphone, ios, macos, ipad

I developed a login portal for a Wifi hotspot. When I connect to that hostpot, the CNA appears with no problem, and I can go through the entire process of login. However, when it comes to reach the "Success.html" page, the CNA doesn't close itself. The page is just display and the user can see "Success" on the screen.

The user is redirected to this page using JS (I tried both window.open and window.location.href commands).

Any clue on how I can make this page close? Is there a specific way to redirect the user to this "Success" page to make the CNA understand it should be closed?

Additional info: The login portal is under https. I don't know if it has anything to do with that...

Thanks a lot!

Nikkow.

Answer (score 0):

Try to intercept the "success" page in a script, after choose the action to do !

Answer (score 0):

If the captive portal is detected by the Captive Network Assistant.app (located in /System/Library/CoreServices/) then the user will hav to click the “Done” button to close the window. You might not be allowed to intercept that as it might be a security vulnerability. See if you can do what @Lord St. John suggests.